# gnome-shell doesn't install due to held broken packages

Tags: 11.10, gnome

When I install gnome-shell in ubuntu 11.10, The following error appear

```
gnome-shell : Depends: gnome-icon-theme-full but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Have any PPAs around that you added manually?

Comment: I did resolve it by changing my update server. I did not notice that the FPT Server in Vietnam is not up to date. That causes the error

Answer (score 1):

You should install Synaptic Package Manager with `sudo apt-get install synaptic`, and then open it. Then, go to Edit > Fix Broken Packages. Then try to install Gnome Shell again.